# invalid 'times' argument running Random Forest model in R, Problem with the use of CATEGORIC variables

Tags: random-forest

this error message appears already in some posts on this website, But I seem to be stuck with my script at the moment.

I'm trying to run a Random Forest model using numeric and categoric variables. When starting Run 1, I get this error message :

Error in rep(NA, nb.var - length(r$Overall)) : invalid 'times' argument

Here what my data looks like

```
  ID pres         X        Y depot drainage       dtw    slope    elev
1  1    N -70.25613 46.10049     1        2   83.7994 2.202330 482.585
2  2    N -70.28433 46.10076     2        4 1012.5500 0.375789 580.474
3  3    N -70.28325 46.10078     2        4  936.9060 0.127978 580.054
4  4    N -70.28217 46.10080     2        4  862.7680 2.326060 576.360
5  5    N -70.28108 46.10082     2        4  790.5620 2.236280 572.330
6  6    N -70.28000 46.10084     2        4  720.8700 0.698591 569.923
```

"depot" and "drainage" are categoric and were coded to be factors.

Here is my script:

```
for (m in c("RF")) {      # m = method used: RF, GLM
  for (n in c(87)) {       # n = number of pseudo-absences
    for (i in c(1:100)) {        # i = number of repetitions, we chose 100
      cat("Starting run", i,"\n")
      
      presences <- sites[sites$pres == "Y",]
      absences <- sites[sites$pres == "N",]
      absences <- absences[sample(c(1:dim(absences)[1]), n),]
      
      selected.sites <- rbind(presences, absences)
      
      #selected.sites[which(selected.sites == 0)] <- NA
      
      train.data <- createDataPartition(selected.sites$pres, p = .7, list = FALSE)
      
      training <- selected.sites[train.data,]
      testing <- selected.sites[-train.data,]
      
      preProcValues <- preProcess(training[, -c(1:4)], method = c("center", "scale"))
      
      training[, -c(1:4)] <- predict(preProcValues, training[, -c(1:4)])
      testing[, -c(1:4)] <- predict(preProcValues, testing[, -c(1:4)])
      
      # Check for near zero variables
      nzv <- nearZeroVar(training[, -c(1:4)], saveMetrics = TRUE) #if there were some we would have to script in to remove them
      
      if (m == "RF") {
        fitControl <- trainControl(
          method = "cv",
          number = 10,
          classProbs = T,
          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
        )
        modelFit <- train(
          form = pres ~ .,
          data = training[, -c(1,3,4)],
          method = "rf",
          #tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)),
          family = "binomial",
          trControl = fitControl,
          metric = "ROC",
          model = FALSE
        )
        
        df <- data.frame(varImp(modelFit)$importance)
        df$Var <- row.names(df)
        r <- df[sort(df$Var),]
        varimps[i,] <- c(r$Overall, rep(NA, nb.var - length(r$Overall)))

        names <- rownames(r)
        png(paste0(out.png.dir, "pp", m, "_", n, "_", i, ".png"), units="in", width=11, height=11, res=300)
        par(mfrow = c(4, 4), xpd = NA) #one page only (overwrites) so adjust number according to N variables
        for (name in names) {
          pp <- partialPlot(modelFit$finalModel, training, eval(name), main=name, xlab=name)
        }
        dev.off()
```

In this script nb.var is 5 and refers to the 5 tested variables.

The object "r" has a lenght of 15 because of the categoric variables. I think the problem is there, but I'm not sure how to correct the script. I'm used to running RF models with only numeric variables and it is the first time I try using categoric variables.

I tried modifying the line with the rep function to nb.var - nb.var thinking I was mimicking what the script was doing when I had only numeric variables, but this got me the following error message :

Error in varimps[i, ] <- c(r$Overall, rep(NA, nb.var - nb.var)) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

May I be missing something else in this script that I'm repurposing.